# Processbuilder in not taking the input from OutputStream in java

Tags: java, batch-file, process, processbuilder

I have a requirement, where I will be executing a batch file in java. On completion, the batch script waits for the user input. Then I have to pass two commands, each command followed by the enter key. Please find my code below,

```
        File batchFile = new File("batch file path");            
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        builder.command(batchFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Process process = builder.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                process.getOutputStream()));
        String s;
        loop:
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("$: " + s);
            if (s.contains("last line before user input. so i am breaking here")) {
                break loop;
            }
        }
        writer.write("Command1");
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
        writer.write("Command2");
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
        writer.write("/close");
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("$: " + s);
        }
```

**Issue:**
Though I am sending input through the bufferedwriter, the process is not getting the input.Can someone give me any pointers to fix this issue. The program runs till the last while loop. When it enters the last while loop statement, it is getting hanged. It looks like the process is still waiting for the user input, so reader.readLine() in the while statement waits infintely. I have been searching for a solution for the whole day, but still no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "the process is not getting the input" How do you know it's not? Can you show us how the other process implemented?

Comment: @Joni I am sure the process is not getting the input, because the reader.readline() in the last while loop was hanging. I read in some post, reader.readline() hangs when it waits for the user input because it will not get null. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @Joni interactive command prompt with a batch script seems impossible. Searched a lot around the internet. reader.readline() hangs when it reaches the point where the program prompts for the user input.

Comment: Are you certain that the hang is at the second loop and not the first loop? Maybe you step through in debugger as there is no System.out.println in between the loops.

Comment: @DuncG if I don't use a break statement in the first while loop, it hangs there itself. The issue is reader.readline() hangs when it encounters a user input prompt. So I am breaking at the first while loop and trying to send commands through the output stream.

Comment: @DuncG the same program works in a mac system with a shell script instead of a batch script.